# Convert Geopandas Multipolygon to Polygon

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely

I have a geodataframe with a Multipolygon geometry:

[image]

I would like to convert them to Polygons i.e. fill in the holes of multipolygon and make it a single polygon.

I have tried the code from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48082553/convert-multipolygon-to-polygon-in-python):

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPolygon, Polygon
gdf['Polygon'] =  gdf['SHAPE'].apply( lambda x: MultiPolygon(Polygon(p.exterior) for p in x))
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'Polygon' object is not subscriptable
```

I have tried other solutions from stack overflow with no luck.

Any ideas?

Here are the dtypes:

```
FID                 int64
LHO                object
Shape__Area       float64
Shape__Length     float64
SHAPE            geometry
```

Here is the complete code to get the shapefile:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from arcgis import GIS
gis = GIS(verify_cert=False,api_key='your_api_key')

search_result = gis.content.search(query="title:National_LHO", item_type="Feature Layer")

# get layer
layer = search_result[0].layers[0]

# dataframe from layer
df= pd.DataFrame.spatial.from_layer(layer)

gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df)

gdf = gdf.set_geometry('SHAPE')

gdf = gdf.set_crs(epsg='3857')

gdf = gdf.to_crs(epsg='4326')
```

Comment: Can you remove .exterior ?

Comment: Can you also print the dtypes of the columns?

Comment: @anarchy I have edited my post to add dtypes and more info.

Comment: could you paste a copy of the dataframe just a few lines ? because i cant seem to install the arcgis package properly, you could also upload a csv file of just the first few lines as well that would make it easier

Answer (score 19):

There is method called `.explode` you can use on your GeoDataFrame:

```
gdf_exploded=gdf.explode()
```

you can find the docs [here](https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explode.html)